# How to pass/parse server data to objects in WatchKit table rows?

Tags: json, swift, rest, http, watchkit

My tutorial is a WhatsApp/SnapChat app. Naturally the avatar image, country flag, user name, gender symbol and conversation data all come from the server and host app.

These kinds of apps do not use Parse like APIs or other 3rd party dependencies because they use REST/JSON with their own servers.

How do I get this same data and UI elements onto the watch table row? Do we have to re-write the same HTTP GET methods in our watch extension as well as re-copy UI elements into watchOS cassettes folder? Can we not just call the same methods that already exist in the iOS host app? I'm not sure how the Connectivity Framework would be used.

Could you please give an example of GET and POST methods to assign an avatar or username to the watch table row view object? For example for a Node.js server.

[image]

Comment: @petahchristian Thank you. I'm sweating less now :) So based on what you said I just need to use the Connectivity Framework. `sendMessageToWatch` and `didReceiveMessage` methods. Since the host app is written in Obj-C should `WatchConnectivity / WCSessionDelegate` be imported into every file header file that contains data that needs to be sent to the watch extension? Or should I be creating new Swift files in that Obj-C project iOS app folder? I don't need a bridging header file in the watch extension folder of course do I? Only in the host app folder right?

Comment: @petahchristian if you copy your original reply into an answer plus your new reply I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your iOS host app has already downloaded and deserialized the data, it doesn't make any sense for the watch to duplicate that code or effort and GET the same data.

As for providing an example, *you* should show what you tried in code, and explain the specific problem you're having.

## Documentation

You should use the [Watch Connectivity framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WatchConnectivity_framework/) to share data between your iOS and watchOS apps.

You'll find a good introduction in the [watchOS 2 Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleWatch2TransitionGuide/UpdatetheAppCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015234-CH6-SW1).  See *Communicating with Your Companion iOS App* for details.

Apple also provides [Lister sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Lister/Introduction/Intro.html) which demonstrates how to use [`WCSession`](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/WCSession) to transfer both application context and files between iOS and watchOS.

> Since the host app is written in Obj-C should WatchConnectivity / WCSessionDelegate be imported into every file header file that contains data that needs to be sent to the watch extension?

`WCSession` is a singleton that you configure at launch time, early in the life of both your iOS app and watch extension.  See the transition guide's *Activating the Session Object* for more information.

If you don't understand how or where your apps should handle watch connectivity, there are plenty of tutorials and sample projects which you can easily find via Google.

> So based on what you said I just need to use the Connectivity Framework. `sendMessageToWatch` and `didReceiveMessage` methods.

The exact methods you use depend on what you want to transfer -- application context, user info, files, or messages -- and whether it takes place in the foreground or background.  See the transition guide's *Choosing the Right Communication Option* for more information.

Comment: I'd be using `WCSessionUserInfoTransfer` and `WCSession` for this chat app. I know how to import WatchConnectivity and create WCSession methods. The problem is documentation and tutorials only present manual sample data to send to the rows in an iOS app.  How do you send 300 users worth of avatars, messages, usernames, and message strings to separate chat rows on the watch? I haven't seen what the deserialized data will look like yet so I guess that's why it's mysterious. I don't know what the arrays will look like.

Comment: You don't transfer data directly to chat rows.  You batch up data and send batches to the watch extension. If you carefully read the documentation I gave you, it said "consider keeping the total number of rows to 20 or fewer. For tables that require more rows, consider loading only a subset of rows initially and then provide the user with controls to load more rows." You have no idea how the data is organized, yet you want me to (keep explaining abstract concepts and) give you code to do what you want. It's unrealistic, not to mention off-topic.  Good luck with your app or tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

If you check some chat app projects that are already on GitHub you will see how to use Connectivity Framework precisely. Obj-C and Swift.

Here's one that specifically shows you how to pass messages back and forth.
https://github.com/carbamide/MessagingTest

This is not my code. As you can see code is almost the same.

ViewController.swift

```
override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
        let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
        session.delegate = self
        session.activateSession()
    }
}


func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : AnyObject]) {
    print(applicationContext)

    let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Application Context Received", message: applicationContext.description, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alert.addAction(okButton)

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

watchOS InterfaceController.swift

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : AnyObject]) {
    print(applicationContext)

    let okButton = WKAlertAction(title: "OK", style: WKAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { () -> Void in })

    self.presentAlertControllerWithTitle("Application Context Received", message: applicationContext.description, preferredStyle: .Alert, actions: [okButton])
}
```